# Get pydoc help() to ignore reST (sphinx) syntax?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pydoc

I have some function definitions like this:

```
def abc(arrg1):
    """
    do something
    :param arrg1: a string like ``'gogo'``
    """
    if arrg1=='gogo':
        print('success')
```

which generates into a nice Sphinx HTML document formatted like this:

> ```
> abc(arrg1)
>    do something 
>
>    Parameters:arrg1 – a string like 'gogo'
> ```

but in the interactive terminal, it looks really confusing, especially for new users or non-programmers:

```
>>> help(abc)
Help on function abc in module __main__:

abc(arrg1)
    do something
    :param arrg1: a string like ``'gogo'``
```

I'm specifically referring to this:

```
``'gogo'``
```

it's really unhelpful for the new users, who often use these sort of pydoc help commands.

---

Is there any way to make the **help**  output cleaner, basically ignoring/stripping the backticks?

Comment: Python **already** isn't a HTML language...

Comment: IMO, using double backticks is confusing. Suggest their removal.

Comment: @StevePiercy confusing when in interactive mode, yes, but they make the online documentation easier to read

Comment: @U9-Forward umm, I'm not sure how to respond... I'm using the documentation-generator Sphinx to generate the HTML docs...